# One method to handle all textbox clicks

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, event-handling

Is there an alternative rather then doing this:

```
Private Sub clicktxtBox(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _

    txt_Time_00_000.Click, _
    txt_Time_00_001.Click, _
    txt_Time_00_002.Click, _
    txt_Time_00_003.Click, _
    txt_Time_00_004.Click

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in all the textboxs put the same click event handler.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**No, that's *exactly* how you are supposed to link one event handler method to multiple events.**
The `Handles` keyword in VB.NET is designed to make this very easy.

This [how-to article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3exstx90.aspx) describes exactly the same process:

```
Private Sub ButtonClickHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
    Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click

    ' Add event-handler code here.
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't envisage a simpler alternative